# ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'emailTemplate.vm' in any resource loader

Tags: java, spring, velocity

I am doing an application in springs with maven. i wrote all properties in app.properties  file

file structure is like this

```
                         src/main/resource

                             |_
                             |   templates
                             |        |_mytempaltefile.vm    
                             |_ app.properties
```

i gave the path(absloute) in app.property

app.properties file

```
template.base.path=D\:/SVN/trunk/tfbdirect/src/main/resources/templates
```

utilities-spring.xml

```
<bean id="velocityEngine"
    class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="velocityProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="resource.loader">file</prop>
            <prop key="file.resource.loader.class">
                org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader
            </prop>
            <prop key="file.resource.loader.path">${template.base.path}</prop>
            <prop key="file.resource.loader.cache">false</prop>
        </props>
       </property>
</bean>
```

my class

```
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Map;
 import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
 import org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineUtils;
 import com.providerpay.tfbdirect.service.mail.MailSenderService;

 public class LoginServiceImpl implements ILoginService{

/**
 * Injected through Spring IOC
 */
ILoginDAO loginDAO;
ClaimRuleProcessServiceImpl claimRuleProcessServiceImpl;
PlatformTransactionManager txmanager;

//IForgotPasswordDAO forgotPasswordDAO;

private VelocityEngine velocityEngine;

private String appURL;
private MailSenderService mailSenderService;




TFBLogger log = TFBLoggerFactory.getLogger(RuleServer.class);



public String getAppURL() {
    return appURL;
}

public void setAppURL(String appURL) {
    this.appURL = appURL;
}

public MailSenderService getMailSenderService() {
    return mailSenderService;
}

public VelocityEngine getVelocityEngine() {
    return velocityEngine;
}


public void setVelocityEngine(VelocityEngine velocityEngine) {
    this.velocityEngine = velocityEngine;
}

public void setMailSenderService(MailSenderService mailSenderService) {
    this.mailSenderService = mailSenderService;
}

public ILoginDAO getLoginDAO() {
    return loginDAO;
}
public void setLoginDAO(ILoginDAO loginDAO) {
    this.loginDAO = loginDAO;
}
public ClaimRuleProcessServiceImpl getClaimRuleProcessServiceImpl() {
    return claimRuleProcessServiceImpl;
}
public void setClaimRuleProcessServiceImpl(
        ClaimRuleProcessServiceImpl claimRuleProcessServiceImpl) {
    this.claimRuleProcessServiceImpl = claimRuleProcessServiceImpl;
}   
public void setTxmanager(PlatformTransactionManager txmanager) {
    this.txmanager = txmanager;
}



/**
 * Validates Login
 * @param loginView
 * @return
 */
public boolean isValidLogin(LoginView loginView) {

    /* create tx definition object */
    DefaultTransactionDefinition paramTransactionDefinition = new     DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    TransactionStatus status = txmanager.getTransaction(paramTransactionDefinition );
    boolean result = false;

    try{
        LoginEntity loginEntity = BeanMapper.INSTANCE.viewToEntityMapper(loginView);
        Feedback feedback = claimRuleProcessServiceImpl.validateClaimEligibility(loginEntity);
        log.info( "Rule executed was " +feedback.getAll());

        for (FeedbackMessage feedbackmessaage :feedback.getAll())
        {
            log.info("\n--------------");
            log.info(feedbackmessaage.getRuleCd());
            log.info(feedbackmessaage.getMessage());
            log.info(feedbackmessaage.getSeverity().getName());
            log.info("\n--------------");
        }

        result = loginDAO.isValidLogin(loginEntity);
        log.debug("result = {}", result);

        txmanager.commit(status);

    }catch(Exception e){
        txmanager.rollback(status);
        throw new TfbException("Error occured while validating login credentials");
    }

    return result; 
}




@Autowired
VelocityEngine velocityengine;
public boolean mailResetLink(LoginView loginView) {

    String toEmailAddress;
    LoginEntity loginEntity = BeanMapper.INSTANCE.viewToEntityMapper(loginView);

    /* getting user Email from DAO*/
    toEmailAddress = loginDAO.getEmailByUsername(loginEntity);

    if(toEmailAddress != null && toEmailAddress.trim().length() > 0)
    {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("user", loginEntity);
        model.put("appURL", appURL);
        String body = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "emailTemplate.vm","UTF-8", model);

        mailSenderService.sendMail("from mail", toEmailAddress, "Password Reset Link",body);


    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean resetPassword(LoginView loginView) 
{

    LoginEntity loginEntity = BeanMapper.INSTANCE.viewToEntityMapper(loginView);

    return loginDAO.resetPassword(loginEntity);
}
}
```

every thing fine but i need to change the absolute path to relative path.. i tried many   ways.

i tried like following

```
template.base.path=/templates/
```

but still getting below error .

ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'emailTemplate.vm' in any resource loader.

can any one help me..

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you instantiate the VelocityEngine instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are falling into a common pitfall when using velocity with spring : you place your templates in one location and use a resource loader that searches them in another place. So you have 2 common usages :

- put templates in classpath (as you do) and use `ClasspathResourceLoader`

  ```
  resource.loader = class
  class.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
  ```

  it is simple with little dependencies, but it forces you to put templates in classpath ...
- put templates under `WEB-INF` (as you would do for JSPs) and use `WebappResourceLoader` from velocity tools

  ```
  resource.loader=webapp
  webapp.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader
  webapp.resource.loader.path=/WEB-INF/velocity/
  ```

  it is more natural for a template location, but you add a dependency on velocity tools.

And let spring manage dependencies but not instanciating via `new` ...

Comment: When using either option with Spring Boot, would you put these configurations into application.properties? I'm having trouble getting any class loader to work, doesn't seem to matter which folder I put my templates in.

Comment: how to config that in a yaml config file?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem recently with karaf OSGi framework.
In a CXF resource class (Login in this context) you have to initialize the Velocity Engine like this:

```
public Login() {
    /*  first, get and initialize an engine  */
    ve = new VelocityEngine();        
    ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
    ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
    ve.init();
}
```

Then, in the web method, instantiate the template:

```
    /*  create a context and add data */
    synchronized (initLock) {
        if (loginTemplate == null) {
            loginTemplate = ve.getTemplate("templates/login.vm");
        }
    }
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work out to load the template immediately  after the `ve.init()` call in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems correct. If you instantiate the VelocityEngine instance using "new", try following:

```
@Autowired
VelocityEngine velocityEngine;
```

Comment: If using spring, **avoid** instanciating by new beans that should be injected in other beans or which should receive other beans by spring IOC because it will not work ...

Comment: Hi serge i added  the code what you told top of the method but i am getting the same error only                                  @Autowired
VelocityEngine velocityEngine;